# How can I plot data using saved data from .txt file using matplotlib?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, graphing

I'm trying to load a graph using user input data, and my program is supposed to save the values in a txt file with a format that looks like this:

title

x-label

y-label

[a list of x-values]

[a list of y-values]

- each on their own line.

So what I have so far is:

```
def lagre():
    filnavn = input("Hvilket filnavn vil du lagre grafen din med? ")
    fil = open(filnavn, 'w', encoding="UTF-8")
    fil.write(str(label) + "\n")
    fil.write(str(x_akse) + "\n")
    fil.write(str(y_akse) + "\n")
    fil.write(str(x_liste) + "\n")
    fil.write(str(y_liste) + "\n")
    fil.close()
    return

    
def load():
    filnavn_open = input("Hvilken graf vil du åpne? ")
    f = open(filnavn_open, "r")
    print(f.read())
    vise()
    
def vise():
    plt.plot(x_liste, y_liste)
    plt.title(label)
    plt.xlabel(x_akse)
    plt.ylabel(y_akse)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

But it doesn't work, could anybody help?

Comment: Welcome, could you provide the error trace ?

Comment: There's no error, but the graph doesnt have a plot and the axis titles arent showing up:(

Comment: Then, can you provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I'll edit the post with more code!

Answer (score 0):

You read the whole file by using **f.read()**. This means that calling **f.readlines()** afterwards returns an empty list. You can save the file content in a variable and then use this in your plots or just use **f.readlines()**.

Also you should close the file with **f.close()**. Alternatively you can use the **with ... as** statement.

So for example:

```
def load():
    filnavn_open = input("Which graph do you want to open?")
    with open(filnavn_open, "r") as f:
        filecontent=f.read()
    print(filecontent)
    
    # plots with filecontent
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your approach:

1. the parameter`size` of the `readline` doesn't do what want to do, you can check out the documentation.
2. The x and y values need to be converted from `str` to `list`, the `ast` package does that.

Here is a working version:

```
import ast
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def load():
    filnavn_open = input("Which graph do you want to open? ")
    lines = ['title', 'xlabel', 'ylabel', 'x-values', 'y-values']
    with open(filnavn_open, "r") as f:
        g = {val: f.readline().strip() for val in lines}
    plt.plot(ast.literal_eval(g['x-values']), ast.literal_eval(g['y-values']))
    plt.title(g['title'])
    plt.xlabel(g['xlabel'])
    plt.ylabel(g['ylabel'])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```